# Where is the 'Access Rules' in Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, rules, users

I want to restrict site registration by email domain.

It used to be under <kbd>Administration</kbd> → <kbd>User Mgmt</kbd>.

I can't see any similar, or has this functionality been removed from the standard module set?

Answer (score 3):

For anyone that might be asking the same question - email and username rules were moved to a separate module: [User Restrictions](http://drupal.org/project/user_restrictions).

http://drupal.org/node/1020672

Answer (score 1):

This functionality was removed in Drupal 7, but I guess you are on a lucky day,  [there is a module](http://drupal.org/node/1458148) that implements this same function.

I have never tried it; you mileage may vary.

Comment: The link you have given is for a project application, with which a user is trying to get permission to create projects. It is not said that the new project is created.

Comment: this is a module: https://www.drupal.org/project/email_domain_restriction